# Selenium with Java - error in using sendKeys() function

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

`sendKeys` function is displaying following error in the code:

> The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Error line code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Bharat");
```

I'm importing following librariers:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Java Version: 1.8.0_281
Selenium: 3.141.59

Appreciate you help

Comment: It wants an array of Strings instead.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23624169/13464279) answer you can try `driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(new String[]{"Bharat"});`. But also check your compiler compliance level: look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103315/13464279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655130/13464279)

Comment: Thanks Jems, that solved the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet, so leaving this)

Can you provide more context

- full stacktrace of the error
- surrounding code/ the html of what you are referencing
- what are you trying to accomplish

Browserstack says this is the way to send keys to an input field: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/sendkeys-in-selenium

1. Make sure `driver.findElement(By.name("username"))` is actually the element name of the input field
2. Set a breakpoint, and check `driver.findElement(By.name("username"))` gets the element you want